# How to make an on/off switch using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

so when a user clicks on a link a specific element should be shown and when the user clicks that link again the element should hide.I m trying do it but there's a problem with my code.It occurs just once.I want to occur for infinite times.Can anyone help?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #test {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: black;
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      var yes = 10;
      for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (yes == 10) {
          document.getElementById("test1").onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById("test").style.cssText = "display:block;"
            yes = yes + 1;
            if (yes == 11) {
              document.getElementById("test1").onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById("test").style.cssText = "display:none;"
                yes = yes - 1;

              }

            }
          }

        }

      }


    }
  </script>
  <a id="test1" href="#">link</a>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Woah, why did you nest the click handler inside of a for loop ? That is an interesting design choice.

Comment: What's with all the loops? Also, `yes` is a terrible name for some sort of counter.

Comment: @TravisJ not to mention the `yes` control variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're doing the loop, but here's how you can do the click part with just one listener:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("test");
document.getElementById("test1").onclick = function() {
  if (el.style.display == "block") {
    el.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    el.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a id="test1">link</a>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set `onclick` only once.

Write the function so that it will first check if the element is visible, and either show it or hide it.

(Also you can use `.style.display` rather than `.style.cssText`)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing way more work than you need to do.

Simply check if the div is currently displayed, if it is, hide it, if it isn't show it.

Your script tag can be reduced to:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('test1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var theDiv = document.getElementById('test');

    if(theDiv.style.display === 'block') {
      theDiv.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      theDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: We wrote almost identical examples, +1 from me. :)